# Javascript Decimal Place Restriction To Specific Number With Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, numbers, decimal, yup

I have some client-side validation against a input type number which

- Will accept any number 0 through 99 with 2 decimal places
- And the values of the decimals must be .00, .25, .33, .5, .67, .75

I've tried with 2 digit length validation but how can I validate specific list of decimal numbers with regex ?

/^\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,2})?$/

**VALID CASES**

5.25

78.5

99.75

**INVALID CASES**

88.12

50.78

Comment: That's a fairly short list of valid decimals so use boolean alternation: `\.(?:00|25|33|5|67|75)`. Also `^\d{1,2}` allows for stuff like `00` and `06` so I'm not sure if that's intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write the pattern as:

```
^\d{1,2}\.(?:00|[72]5|33|67|50?)$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `\d{1,2}` Match 1 or 2 digits
- `\.` Match a dot
- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternatives

  - `00|[72]5|33|67|50?` match `00` `75` `25` `33` `67` `5` or `50`
- `)` Close the non capture group
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QQ8LLM/1)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Yes, but there should also be `5` or `50` so then I have to trade that with 5 so it would like like this `^\d{1,2}\.(?:[05]0|[72]5|33|67|5)$`

Answer (score 0):

I would use an alternation for the various allowed decimal endings:

```
^\d{1,2}\.(?:00|25|33|5|67|75)$
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear if you allow leading zeros. Here is a solution if not:

```js
const regex = /^(?:\d|[1-9]\d)\.(?:00|25|33|5|67|75)$/;
[
  '0.33',
  '5.25',
  '78.5',
  '99.75',
  '09.75',
  '88.12',
  '50.78'
].forEach(str => {
  console.log(str + ' => ' + regex.test(str));
});
```

Output:

```
0.33 => true
5.25 => true
78.5 => true
99.75 => true
09.75 => false
88.12 => false
50.78 => false
```

Explanation of regex:

- `^` -- anchor at start of string
- `(?:\d|[1-9]\d)` -- non-capture group: either a single digit, or two digits 10...99
- `\.` -- literal dot
- `(?:00|25|33|5|67|75)` -- non-capture group: local `or` of allowed decimals
- `$` -- anchor at end of string